# Cannot checkout a local svn repository via file://

Tags: svn

on my local machine I created a svn repository and filled it with my svn dump from another server.

```
svnadmin create foo
svnadmin load --ignore-uuid foo < svn.dump
```

Now I want to checkout the trunk branch from the local file system to work on it. But when I try to check it out, in a folder next to it, I always get the hole repository.

```
svn checkout file:///data/foo/
```

Of course I tried it with trunk or a branch name at the end. This results in the following message:

```
svn: E170000: URL 'file:///data/foo/trunk' doesn't exist
```

Which makes sense since the path does not exist:

```
$ ls
conf  db  format  hooks  locks  README.txt
```

I cannot figure out how to checkout the branch and I could not find what I need in **svn checkout --help**.

Does someone have a hint how to do it or if it is really not possible?

Thank you in advance.

Regards,
Hoall

Comment: You should use `svn ls file:///data/foo/` to identify the top level directories in your imported repository.

Comment: Thank you, that was the right hint. After seeing the correct path, it did work out. Do you want to formulate it as answer? Otherwise I answer my own question :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The use of `ls` is unhelpful as `svn` uses a database to store the repository.

Use: `svn ls file:///data/foo/` to identify the top level directories in your imported repository.

See [this document](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.list.html) for details.